# Unable to add dictionary item to listBox

Tags: c#, windows, .net

I have a dictionary with several items in it:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> vmDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

And I have a method to add the items from within it to a listbox:

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> entry in MyApp.vmDictionary)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.SubItems.Add(entry.Value[0]);
            item.SubItems.Add(entry.Value[1]);
            selectVMListView.Items.Add(
```

}

Although I get the following error:

> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'

Relating to these lines:

```
            item.SubItems.Add(entry.Value[0]);
            item.SubItems.Add(entry.Value[1]);
```

entry.Value[0] and [1] should be string if I am not mistaken, but for some reason its complaining they are chars :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entry.Value` returns the value component of the `KeyValuePair<,>`, which in this case is a `string`, when you then use an index on this `string`, you are getting a char. I think what you mean to have is the following:

```
item.SubItems.Add(entry.Key);
item.SubItems.Add(entry.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    item.SubItems.Add(entry.Value[0]);
    item.SubItems.Add(entry.Value[1]);
```

You are trying to add first char of Value in KeyValuePair. Maybe you are trying to do this?

```
    item.SubItems.Add(entry.Key);
    item.SubItems.Add(entry.Value);
```